# Find assemblies in subfolder of primary assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio

I'm using the following handler to resolve assemblies in a specifically named subfolder of the main assembly's folder.

I am looking for improvements in:

- clarity
- correctedness
- flexibility, as long as it doesn't conflict with other goals of this code

The code does not need to be thread-safe as the intended environment is single-threaded.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using static System.IO.Path;
using static System.StringComparison;
using static System.Reflection.Assembly;
using System.IO;

namespace Periscope.Debuggee {
    public static class SubfolderAssemblyResolver {
        public static void Hook(string subfolderKey) {
            if (subfolderKey.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) { return; }
            if (subfolderPath.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) { return; }

            subfolderPath = Combine(
                GetDirectoryName(GetCallingAssembly().Location),
                subfolderKey
            );
            basePath = GetDirectoryName(subfolderPath);

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += resolver;
        }

        private static bool IsNullOrWhitespace([NotNullWhen(false)]this string? s) => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s);
        private static bool EndsWithAny(this string s, StringComparison comparisonType, params string[] testStrings) => testStrings.Any(x => s.EndsWith(x, comparisonType));

        private static readonly string[] exclusions = new[] { ".xmlserializers", ".resources" };
        private static readonly string[] patterns = new[] { "*.dll", "*.exe" };

        private static string? basePath;
        private static string? subfolderPath;

        private static Assembly? resolver(object sender, ResolveEventArgs e) {
            var loadedAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(a => a.FullName == e.Name);
            if (loadedAssembly is { }) { return loadedAssembly; }

            var n = new AssemblyName(e.Name);
            if (n.Name.EndsWithAny(OrdinalIgnoreCase, exclusions)) { return null; }

            // search in basePath first, as it's probably the better dependency
            var assemblyPath =
                resolveFromFolder(basePath!) ??
                resolveFromFolder(subfolderPath!) ??
                null;

            if (assemblyPath is null) { return null; }

            return LoadFrom(assemblyPath);

            string resolveFromFolder(string folder) =>
                patterns
                    .SelectMany(pattern => Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, pattern))
                    .FirstOrDefault(filePath => {
                        try {
                            return n.Name.Equals(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(filePath).Name, OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                        } catch {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

It is called as follows:

```
SubfolderAssemblyResolver.Hook("ExpressionTreeVisualizer");
```

---

#### Background

It is possible to [write a custom debugging visualizer for Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data?view=vs-2019); when you place the compiled DLL into a [specific folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-install-a-visualizer?view=vs-2019) (either `My Documents\%VisualStudioVersion%\Visualizers` or `%VisualStudioInstallPath%\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers`) the visualizer can provide a custom view of an object in the debug session.

Third-party DLLs can be used by the custom visualizer, as long as they are in the same folder as the visualizer DLL.

The problem with this is: if two visualizers use different versions of the same third-party dependency, one of them is liable to break. Also, when deleting the custom visualizer, deleting the dependencies risks breaking other visualizers.

This is compounded by the [architecture needed to apply the visualizer to other framework "families"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-install-a-visualizer?view=vs-2019). The visualizer is split into two parts:

1. the view DLL, targeting .NET Framework (because VS targets .NET Framework); and
2. the debuggee-side DLL, injected into the debugged process

The debuggee-side code can be potentially multitargeted to three variants: `net2.0`, `netcoreapp` and `netstandard2.0`; which means potentially three additional DLLs in three additional subfolders, each of which has its own dependencies and the dependency management issues I've described.

The code in this post allows placing all the dependencies for a given visualizer in a named subfolder alongside the main DLL (either the debugger-side or the debuggee-side).